# jquery mobile, table always reflowing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am facing problems with jquery-mobile tables (with data-role="table").
My table is always reflowing (even with full hd screens), here's the link
[to the demo page](http://demo.cloudun.org/pm/agib.html).

I've tried with both jquery-mobile 1.3 and 1.4b, but the result is still the same.

Doctype declared and valid html5 (except for the encoding)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because by default (= specifying no mode), a table will be in `reflow` mode.

To switch to columnToggle mode, just add `data-mode="columntoggle"` to your table tag, as specified in the [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-columntoggle/)

Comment: Actually, it does work if table tag has "ui-responsive" class. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the class="ui-responsive" and it will work as suggested in the docs of 1.4 and if you want to make  to make the whole table not to go reflow then just add this :

```
@media ( max-width: 35em ) {
    .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td,
    .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        clear: none;
        display: table-cell;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }

}
```

the above code overrides the jquery mobile structure for the same width and stops it from reflowing.